# Android xml listview

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, scroll

I am currently retrieving xml data of current information from my web server and SAX parsing it into a listview in my application. All good if the number of rows generated is small.
If the list grows too large the scrolling starts to choke. I am trying to understand what is the best method of putting a potentially large subset of data into a listview so that it loads rows as required.
Is this in fact the approach to take or do I need to look at another method?

Comment: When asking questions on stackoverflow it's normally expected that you provide example code of what you're trying. In your case also defining what "a potentially large subset of data" means (100, 1000, 10000 items???). `ListView` re-uses its list item `Views` which means it has advantages and disadvantages depending on how your code works. Explaining with more detail and example code will help get you better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look For Lazy and Efficient adapter.

Comment: thank you for your reply i hadnt come across the efficient adapter yet, so i will look at this.